# jQuery remove first td after td that has a class

Tags: jquery

```
 <tr>
    <td class="ms-descriptiontext ms-inputformdescription">
 Accédez au document à télécharger.
   </td>
   <td><img width="8" height="1" alt="" src="/_layouts/images/blank.gif"></td>
 </tr>
```

how can i remove the first td after a td with class ms-descriptiontext ms-inputformdescription

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply:

```
$('td.ms-descriptiontext.ms-inputformdescription').next('td').remove();
```

**Reference**: [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), [`remove`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ms-descriptiontext").siblings("td").eq(1).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("td.ms-descriptiontext.ms-inputformdescription + td").remove();
```